# Linux - /usr/local or /var for application data?

Tags: linux

I'm developing an application that needs to store some data. I'm doubting between storing it in `/usr/local/myapp`, or in `/var/lib/myapp`.

Which is the most suitable directory for this?

Comment: Does it need to write data when running (such as log files or state), or do you mean it need to install header files, libraries or other files when you install the program?

Comment: Have a look at the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As `/usr` is for constant data and `/var` for variable data, use `/var` to store these data.

And, concerning `/usr/local/`: Make sure that packagers can choose to install your software to `/usr/lib/` / `/usr/share` / `/usr/bin` by providing an appropriate variable in your make file.

Software installed manually (i. e. with `make install` etc.) should resinde in `/usr/local/*`, while software packaged via .rpm / .deb / whatever should avoid `/usr/local` and directly be installed under the appropriate folders in `/usr`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *Each* of the folders I mentionned has its equivalen in `/usr/local`.